# how to fix partial black screen on virtual box ubuntu linux

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, guest-additions

[black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hT6G.png)

[image]

I have tried reinstalling linux and guest additions but so far nothing and i can't find anything online.
The only things i can do is click on the side bar but when i try and use the apps nothing happens and cant use them.  I have  already done `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and still nothing.

Comment: Same problem here. Pathetic Canonical testing capabilties.

Answer (score 2):

Install Guest Additions again and restart the machine.

If you installed `build-essentials` after you installed Guest Additions, they were not properly built. You need ti install them again.

Also restarting the machine is needed to use the new driver.

Comment: i installed build-essentials before i added guest additions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04.

I fixed by increasing the Video Memory to 128MB, increasing base memory and adding 1 more CPU.